# How to cast DataView to DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datasource

is there any way to convert DataView to DataSource?

I'm trying to sort my gridview columns on click. Here is the code:

```
internal static string sort(object _sender, GridViewSortEventArgs _e, string _viewStateSortExpression, string _viewStateSortDirection)
        {
            string expression = _e.SortExpression;
            string direction = getSortDirection(expression, _viewStateSortExpression, _viewStateSortDirection); //ascending by default

            GridView gvSrc = (GridView)_sender;

            DataView dv = new DataView();
            gvSrc.DataSource = dv;
            gvSrc.DataBind();



            dv = (DataView)((SqlDataSource)gvSrc.DataSource).Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);


            dv.Sort = expression + " " + direction;
            return direction;
        }
```

I get this error when I click the column to do the sorting:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource'.
```

Comment: Did you try casting directly instead of first casting to `SqlDataSource` and then to `DataView`?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I get this error: DataTable must be set prior to using DataView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Convert DataView to DataTable**:

there is a method named ToTable to convert DataView to DataTable

```
DataTable dt=dv.ToTable();// this method may expects parameters
```

**Convert DataTable to DataView**:

DefaultView is a property that returns DataView of a DataTable

```
DataView dv=dt.DefaultView
```

Comment: GridView gvSrc = (GridView)_sender;
            DataView dv = new DataView();
            gvSrc.DataSource = dv;
            gvSrc.DataBind();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = dv.ToTable();
          
  dv = dt.DefaultView;
            

This throws an error as well: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 DataTable m_DataTable = gvSrc.DataSource as DataTable;

   if (m_DataTable != null)
   {
      DataView m_DataView = new DataView(m_DataTable);
      m_DataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

      gvSrc.DataSource = m_DataView;
      gvSrc.DataBind();
   }
```